# AttributeError: 'RunCmd' object has no attribute 'p', Python subprocess

Tags: python, multithreading, subprocess

Python program produces this error

```
File ".\check_test.py", line 57, in Run
    self.p.terminate()
AttributeError: 'RunCmd' object has no attribute 'p'
```

Python Code:
First, I call the subprocess

```py
subprocess.call(["g++", "test.cpp"])
problem = RunCmd(["./a.exe"], TimeLimit).Run()
```

RunCmd:

```py
class RunCmd(Thread):
    def __init__(self, cmd, timeout):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.cmd = cmd
        self.timeout = timeout

    def run(self):
        #self.p is set to None, why does the subprocess fail? (self.cmd is executed and i obtain the result expected by subprocess)
        self.p = subprocess.Popen(self.cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, close_fds=True)

        if self.p.stderr is None:
            self.p.stdout = (self.p.stdout.read()).decode("utf-8")
            self.p.return_code = self.p.returncode
        else:
            self.p.stdout = None
            self.p.stderr = self.p.stderr.decode("utf-8")

        print(self.p.poll())   #return None
        self.p.wait()

    def Run(self):
        self.start()
        self.join(self.timeout)

        if self.is_alive():
            self.p.terminate() #self here has no attribute 'p'
            self.join()
            return True
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\check_test.py", line 134, in <module>
    problem = RunCmd(["./a.exe"], TimeLimit).Run()
  File ".\check_test.py", line 57, in Run
    self.p.terminate()
AttributeError: 'RunCmd' object has no attribute 'p'
None
```

What is wrong exactly?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're mixing `.run()` and `.Run()`. You're running the latter, while the former is the one setting `p` - and I don't see where you're calling `.run()`.

Comment: I first call the `.Run()` yes, which invokes `.run()` by the following line `self.start()`
start()
Start the thread’s activity.

Comment: Did you write your own `.start()` or is inherited from `Thread`?